# What should be our motto?

Tags: discussion

A lot of sites have a special motto. It is usually funny, interesting and catchy. I think we should have a catchy motto too. So what do you think our motto should be? Make it as awesome, catchy, and more interesting as you can! All ideas are okay!

Comment: I'm from Germany and my English is not the best. Because of that I like the actual tagline. It describes the site in an understandable English!

Comment: 'Funny' is a bit subjective - are you after wit? puns? something actually humorous, or just clever?

Answer (score 2):

Not Just another Drink, But A Caffeinated Gateway to Zen

A Caffeinated Calling

Brewing the perfect roast

Comment: I quite like "Brew the perfect roast"

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions:

- Serving Coffee and Knowledge Since 2015
- Coffee.SE - Official Q/A for Coffee-ers!
- Coffee + Knowledge = Coffee.SE

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something about the correlation between the facts that caffeine is both the least regulated psychoactive drug in the world and also the most widely used …

Nah.  It's funny, but not hah-hah funny.

**Coffee is drank in many ways: sweet, creamy, spiced, or pure.

And, for those who have it spiked, it doubles as a cure.**

Whoops.  That's no good.

How about this?

### The internet is all a-buzz about Coffee.SE

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- Coffee.SE: overthinking coffee since 2015.
- Where *real* coffee nerds learn about *real* coffee.
- Coffee + Science: FUN
- Serious coffee questions need serious answers.

Comment: Okay -- perhaps I misunderstood the point of "a motto" and this discussion: I was aiming for a "funny" motto, in the style of [the Stack Overflow motto discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7436/262760). I was aiming for some eye-catching, *wry* tag-line for community ads or so. If not, our *dry* "current description" is as good as can be, and is exactly the same style as the other sites @fredley listed...

Comment: I quite like "Serious coffee questions need serious answers" but perhaps shortened a little, something like "Serious coffee needs serious knowledge" or something?

Answer (score 0):

> **The text below is the opinion of the answerer. Please don't read if**
>   **you're allergic to opinions.**

My suggestions:

- Where coffee and questions meet (A bit misleading?)
- No, we do not serve **decaf**. (Too funny?)
- For coffee addicts who want points

Comment: Ah…Ah…*A-tchoo!*

Answer (score 0):

#### Similar to 'covfefe', except it's not.

<sub>okay, I know this is pretty much out of date already but I had to...</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Coffee SE - Jittery with knowledge

Answer (score -3):

**Keep calm and drink coffee**

[image: Keep calm; drink coffee]
<sup>Original image [**here**](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/keep-calm-and-drink-coffee-400.png).</sup>

Comment: Not so original...

Comment: @PythonMaster That's fine.